# Two smallest values of a array without sorting

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I would like to make a function to return the two smallest values without sorting it.

The issue I have is that I get the following error :

> main.c:9:25: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'int'
>    struct findTwoSmallests(int *p,int size)
>   main.c: In function 'main
>   main.c:56:8: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Struct_Elements' from type 'int'
>        r2 = findTwoSmallests(p_array,N);

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Struct_Elements 
{
    int min1;
    int min2;
};

struct findTwoSmallests(int *p,int size)
{
    int i, smallest, secondSmallest;
    struct Struct_Elements r;

    smallest = p[0];
    secondSmallest=p[0];

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(p[i]>smallest)
        {
            if(p[i]<secondSmallest || smallest==secondSmallest)
                secondSmallest = p[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(secondSmallest>smallest && p[i]!=smallest)
                secondSmallest=smallest;

            smallest = p[i];
        }
    }

    r.min1 = smallest;
    r.min2 = secondSmallest;

    printf("smallest:%d secondSmallest:%d\n\n", smallest, secondSmallest);

    return r;
}

int main()
{
    struct Struct_Elements r2;
    int N, i;
    int *p_array;

    printf("Array Size : ");
    scanf("%d",&N);

    p_array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*N);     // allocate N ints

    printf("*** Print values ***\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("p_array[%d]=",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&p_array[i]);
    }

    r2 = findTwoSmallests(p_array,N);

    printf("smallest:%d secondSmallest:%d\n\n", r2.min1, r2.min2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct findTwoSmallests(int *p,int size)` should be `struct Struct_Elements findTwoSmallests(int *p,int size)`

Comment: Thanks a lot . It works!